# Entity's deprecated in Hibernate 4. So what should I use instead?

Tags: java, hibernate

I just noticed that the `@Entity` annotation was deprecated in `Hibernate 4`, now I need to replace it somehow. I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

What annotation should I use instead in that case?

Comment: @AleksandrM But I didn't specify the dynamicUpdate property.

Comment: So? Read all answers from that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Entity` is removed you should use `@DynamicUpdate` instead.

Example : Configure `@DynamicUpdate` properties via annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name", catalog = "catalog_name")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
public class ClassName implements java.io.Serializable {

}
```

Comment: Could you please code snippet using with @DynamicUpdate ?